FFmpeg fell into a cycle at concatenation on Ubuntu Desktop i386 16.04.4
I use FFmpeg at 2016 but I need concat much short video from 4 to 180 sec. This is on a notebook with Windows 7 and Ubuntu Desktop i386 16.04.4.
If tool can read filter script from file it cannot input filename from file and will be concated clips many time.
I used FFmpeg on Linux and used links to an input files (0 -> first.mp4, 1 -> second.mp4 e.g
I used such command:
ffmpeg -i 1 -i 2 -i 3 -i 4 -i 5 -i 6 -i 7 -i 8 -sn -filter_complex [0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=8:v=1:a=1 -r 25 Begin25d.mp4
Version of program:
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
) tool concats 2 files very good.
When I gave 13 inputs tool began got warning message "overflow buffer"

PC calculates something long time and continue work until get same warning:

Situation repeated. But on third time PC stoped, nothing functioned, not mouse, not keyboard:

After reboot situation repeated.
On Windows it concats to 15 files, but now I have long filenames and out from command line length.
What is this errors? Why it done?
How I must did to concat 71 short files to one?
....
Thank you Jay finding other path to decise concatination in comments.
But ffmpeg has main goal using many other filters together.
Who does have an interest to find an error i show log file getting at next morning with same warnings and falling to a cycle:
[]log file 4
And i think a problem is on free allocation memory.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hello, mistake #1: no command listed. Mistake #2: using photos of logs/codes, not even screenshots, but they should be copied text in 99% of cases so that browsers can index it and it's searchable on this website.

#!/bin/bash

make_mkv() {
for file in *.{mp4,webm,wmv,avi}; do
  filename="${file%.}"
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file" -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero concat_"$filename".mkv
done

mkdir -p source_files
mv *.{mp4,webm,wmv,avi} ./source_files
}

# switch container before concatenation
# if they're not .mkv, uncomment the next line
# make_mkv

ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *.mkv > tmp.txt
sed 's/^/file /' tmp.txt > list.txt && rm tmp.txt

ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy -avoid_negative_ts auto -movflags +faststart "final_mux.mkv" && rm list.txt

if [[ -f concat_* ]]; then
  rm concat_*
  echo "original videos in 'source_files' directory."
fi

echo "finished: final_mux.mkv"

exit 0

Save as: concat_videos.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x concat_videos.sh
Put this script in the same directory as the files.
Then, run it: ./concat_videos.sh

Thank you, Jay. It's very good decision. And it has working just quickly. All right.

@Nick No problem, my friend.  I don't know the difference, but -filter_complex will not allow concatenation using -c copy.  Using an input list has no problem.

i handshake you. Your decision has not documented and i think such events is much. I have .mp4 videos and used only 3 string: ls --quoting-style=shell-always -1v *.mp4 > tmp.txt sed 's/^/file /' tmp.txt > list.txt && rm tmp.txt ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy -avoid_negative_ts auto -movflags +faststart "out_mux.mp4" Why did you use ῾file῾ before filenames in list? And what will we use other words and where?

@Nick Concat demuxer
